# How to clone a CoreData SQLite backed persistent store to "in memory"?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'd like to create a clone of my CoreData structure (not the data) in memory. This would allow me to write my unit tests with a fresh CoreData stack, and not have to deal with data currently stored in the actual SQLite database.

As a side note I'm using MagicalRecord, which may or not help.

What I have in mind for my unit tests would be something as follow:

- during `- (void)setUp` open the app CoreData store (SQLite)
- clone that store to memory
- close the persistent SQLite store
- open the in memory store just created
- delete all data in the memory store
- run my tests

Any idea? Or better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just skip steps 1, 3, 4, and 5?  They don't look needed to me.  I will write an answer on the assumption that you just need an empty store based on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MagicalRecord contains a function called `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore]`.  This will create an in-memory store based on your data model.  There is no need for copying or any of the stuff you mentioned because this type of store is not persistent (you said you will just delete it all anyway before you actually use it).  So don't worry about cloning the SQL version, just set up a memory version and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following this guide I wrote: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/15/unit-testing-with-core-data/

It goes over the way to set up a stack with an in memory store for use with unit tests.